# Moving select option from one drop down to another does not work with a single option

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the following code to move options from one drop down to another using jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change keyup', '.select-groups', function(){
    moveSelectOptions($(this), 'available-groups', 'selected-groups');
});

var moveSelectOptions = function(elm, source, target){
    var sourceId = source;
    var targetId = target;

    if (elm.attr('id') != sourceId) {
        var sourceId = target;
        var targetId = source;
    }

    return !$('#'+sourceId+' option:selected').remove().appendTo('#' + targetId);
};
```

I'm using both on `change` and on `keyup` events and everything works well, expect when there is only one option left in the dropdown, which in that case the option does not get moved over to the other dropdown.

I tried adding `click` event too but looks like it's conflicting with the other events.

Any idea how this can be resolved? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: when only one option left in the list, then, change event wont get call, as there is no other option to select, thats why it is failing

Comment: what is the issue you are seeing with click event?

Comment: With `click` I have to select a bunch of options and then click outside of the area for the options to move to the other drop down, it's not as responsive and friendly as change.

Comment: Simply you add Dummy `--SELECT--`